# Facebook "publish_actions" permission

Tags: facebook, permissions

I can't publish anything on user timeline when facebook has remove "publish_actions" permission? If it can,how to upload video on user timeline?Or how to review "publish_actions" permission with Graph API v2.12.

Answer (score 13):

> On August 1st, 2018, the Live API publish_actions permission, which
>   allows an app to publish on behalf of its Users, will be reserved for
>   approved partners. **In the coming weeks, a new permission model that
>   allows apps to publish Videos to their User's Groups and Timelines
>   will be announced**.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes

Answer (score 0):

just remove this line of your facebook code

```
 LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
```