# Posting to Facebook with Python and Graph API, Permissions Issue

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Relatively new to interacting with Facebook through the Graph API, so apologies in advance.

I a simply trying to post a facebook status to my own facebook with the python facebook-sdk and the Graph API.

I have authorized a user-access-token with literally every permission:

[Sceenshot of Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0STZ.png)

And then using the API documentation, I am simply doing

```
graph.put_object(parent_object='me', connection_name='feed',
              message='Hello, world')
```

With the graph object built by calling the provided access key.

However, I keep getting this error:

facebook.GraphAPIError: (#200) Requires either publish_to_groups permission and app being installed in the group, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission

Any chance you guys know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Posting to your own feed with the API is not possible anymore, the required permission `publish_actions` has been removed. You can use the share dialog instead.

More information: [Facebook "publish_actions" permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146705/facebook-publish-actions-permission)

Comment: Oh wow...interesting. Thanks!

Now to figure out how to do this with the python api...

Comment: how to do what? it is not possible, and there is only one api. what you mean is the pythin sdk, not python api. you can use the facebook api with the python sdk (or any other sdk). and again: it is not possible, that´s in the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: How would the method for doing this in Koala look like? Instead of `put_object`

Comment: what method exactly? there is no method, publish_actions is gone.