# Facebook Graph API - Deprecated publish_actions alternative

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have an application that uses the Graph API to publish content on a FB User account using publish_actions permission. This is now deprecated and I am trying to figure out if there is an alternative way to make this happen. After searching for answers in SO I am still not sure if this is possible. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353828/posting-to-facebook-with-python-and-graph-api-permissions-issue) it is not - however other posts and FB documentation itself indicate that the [Sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web) API is a valid option, although I am not sure if that's totally true. What I need to do is publish a post with no user interaction other than authorizing the app to publish content. Is this possible with this new security model?

Thanks

Comment: No there is no way to do that

Comment: The Share or Feed dialog are your only option now. The purpose is to let users have full control, because too many apps abused their posting privileges in the past.

Comment: "no user interaction other than authorizing the app to publish content": even with the publish_actions permission, this would not have been allowed. the user would still have needed to approve every single post.